# JS local variable changing global

Tags: javascript, object, scope

In the following script I can't understand why the property prop in the object global is changed by changing the local (private) object local?

```
var global = {}
global.prop = "Global init";

var ChangeState = (function () {    
var local = global;
local.prop = "Changed"; // expecting Global init?

})()

alert("Global = " + global.prop)
```

I am not asking JS to change global, but it changes it anyway? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `global` is a reference to an object.

Inside your function, you copy that reference to `local`.

You then change the value of the `prop` property of that object.

Since `global` and `local` reference the same object, `global.prop` and `local.prop` will always be the same value.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) for details on how to create a copy of an object instead of a copy of the reference.